# Strip Datastax binary to have only Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have downloaded latest Datastax binary - 4.5.2. It comes loaded with hive, hadoop, solr etc etc which I am not interested in. I just want to bundle Cassandra with my product. I tried removing all the folders from dse-4.5.2/resources but cassandra and tried starting cassandra by executing below command from dse-4.5.2/bin

./dse cassandra

However it failed. So looks like its not as simple as deleting folders.

Has any one ever tried this?

Comment: Why not just use apache Cassandra if you only want to bundle Cassandra?

Answer (score 0):

DSE will not use hive, hadoop, solr, etc. unless you explicitly ask it to. 
I.E. in order to start DSE with search run:

```
dse cassandra -s
```

If you just start using `dse cassandra` it will only start the cassandra process.

Comment: Thanks. But the overall size of dse-4.5.2 folder goes to 600+ MB. Since I just want Cassandra, I believe I can strip it and reduce the overall size.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using apache cassandra for this. Here's a puppet module that you might like: https://github.com/heartysoft/puppet-cassandra